# Unable to get the session id from HTTP cookie in CookieContainer WP8 application

Tags: httpwebrequest, windows-phone-8, httpwebresponse, sessionid, cookie-httponly

Preface:

I'm writing a windows phone 8 application, and one of my modules is responsible for communication over a remote server.

I'm using GET and POST methods using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebRequest.

I was also surprised to found out, that HTTP only cookies are not accessible through WP8 apps, 
meaning you can't get, set, or even see them.

As you may know, when you get a response from the server, the Cookies property of a CookieCollection type, is seemingly empty, but, when you use the same code from a console application, you are able to see the cookie, and its content which is the session id.

I wasted many hours and days over forums on how to overcome that issue, 
and the solutions I found relevant was simply to create a new CookieContainer and attach it to every request I'm doing.

This solution worked, but now I got to the stage that I have to actually get the session ID
for other purposes.. Such as using a WebBrowser control, that i need to attach to it a resource from the server, but the only way it will work is by attaching to it the session id also... So I really must get the cookie's value..

Curently, except the WebBrowser problem, every thing is working fine, but the guys I work with told me that in the next step I will must have the session ID for other purposes..

I have tried all sorts of solutions, through reflection and adding C++ unmanaged code and nothing worked.

it just doesnt sound reasonable to me that this is not possible...

Does anybody have solved this problem, and actually has a working code for this?

I'm truly desperate, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess that there's a good explanation to why no one is answering this..

I got an inside word from a Microsoft guy, that this is simply not possible at the moment.

They are expecting an update that will fix the issue in the next half of the year.. that is if you don't want to re-implement the HTTP layer from scratch.